# What part of speech is "up" in the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, prepositional-phrases

1. I walked up to the ATM.
2. I looked up at the sky.

The way I see it, "up" is an adverb in both sentences. Meanwhile, "to the ATM" and "at the sky" are prepositional phrases.

Comment: "Up" is always a preposition in examples like yours. The VP "walked up to the ATM" consists of three constituents: (1) the verb "walked"  + (2) the preposition "up" with no complement + (3) a preposition with an NP complement.

Comment: See [this explanation from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/up). ***Up*** as an ***adverb*** - *She put the books up on the highest shelf*. ***Up*** as a ***preposition*** - *He was up a ladder painting*. But don't worry if you don't understand that distinction - I don't either!

Answer (score 1):

'Up' is a preposition here. According to [Merrian Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up) definition 3, 'up' is a preposition used in similar fashion as your examples.

For the first example sentence in the question, the applicable definition is 2a - "in a direction regarded as being toward or near the upper end or part of".

For the second example sentence in the question, the applicable definition is 1a - "used as a function word to indicate motion to or toward or situation at a higher point of"

Edit based on BillJ's inputs:
Therefore, the prepositional phrases in your sentences will be "to the ATM" and "at the sky".

Comment: I would't go along with you. The VP "walked up to the ATM" consists of three constituents: (1) the verb "walked" + (2) the preposition "up" with no complement + (3) a preposition "to" with the NP complement "the ATM".

Comment: What part would you not go along with? We both call it a preposition, isn't it?

Comment: I explained the structure in my last comment. "Up to the ATM" is not a single constituent, not a PP. It's **two** constituents: (1) the prep "up" and (2) the PP "to the ATM". The same applies to "up at the sky".